# Dependency injection not working in grails job using mail plugin

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have created a *service* `NotifierService` to send emails using grails mail plugin.

```
class NotifierService {
    MailService mailService

    def sendWarningEmail(String name, String email, Date blockingDate) {
        try {
            mailService.sendMail {
                to email
                from "noreply-myApp@domain.com"
                subject "Status message: Warning"
                body (view:"/email/warningEmail", model:[
                                                    name:name, 
                                                    blockingDate:blockingDate
                                                    ])
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I have created another *service* `ApplicationUtilService` in which I am trying to use the `NotifierService`.

```
class ApplicationUtilService{
    def notifierService

    def notifyUser(){
        notifierService.sendWarningEmail("User name", "user@domain.com", new Date())
    }
}
```

I am trying to call `notifyUser()` in a grails job `UpdateJob`

```
class UpdateJob{
    def applicationUtilService

    static triggers = {
        // Scehduling parameters
    }

    def execute(){
        applicationUtilityService.notifyUser()
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
Error 2014-12-05 12:04:53,550 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method notifyUser() on null object
   Line | Method
->> 111 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   202 | run     in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run . . in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread ...`
```

It works when I instantiate as

`ApplicationUtilService applicationUtilService = new ApplicationUtilService()`

instead of using grails dependency injection. Again, the same problem with the `notifierService` in `ApplicationUtilService` and fixed by instantiating same as above.

Now, the real problem is with the `mailService`. The instantiation as above didn't work. How could I resolve it

Comment: have you defined both of your services under `grails-app/services`?

Comment: Yes, defined under services

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using grails version 2.2.4

Comment: are you calling `applicationUtilityService.someFunction()` or `applicationUtilityService.notifyUser()` in your job?

Comment: Oops! It was a mistake. I edited the question. It is actually `notifyUser`, not `someFunction`

Comment: What version of the quartz plugin are you using?

Comment: quartz version 1.0.1

Comment: Not for question, but don't forget to add static transient = false it's a good practise.

Answer (score 1):

The Null Pointer is occurring on UpdateJob.applicationUtilService, so it seems like applicationUtilService isn't being injected into UpdateJob correctly.  Is UpdateJob in the right package?

Comment: Yes, actually all my implementation is in package `com.mydomain.dev`, and I created the job using `create-job com.mydomain.dev.UpdateJob`. It is created under `MyApp/grails-app/jobs/com/mydomain/dev/`